# Contact identifier returns with ABPerson suffix

Tags: ios, cncontact, cncontactstore, cncontactviewcontroller

I am adding contact using Native CNContactViewController and once contact saved it returns contact's identifier with ':ABPerson' suffix and when I cross check in contact list same contact appears with different identifier.

Does anyone know how to get actual contact identifier?

Code to Create:

```
- (IBAction)didSelectedAddContact:(id)sender {
CNMutableContact *contact =  [CNMutableContact new];

CNContactViewController *contactController = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForNewContact:contact];

NSLog(@"contact id : %@", contact.identifier);

contactController.allowsEditing = true;
contactController.allowsActions = true;

contactController.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:contactController animated:YES];    
}
```

Delegate Callback:

```
- (void)contactViewController:(CNContactViewController *)viewController didCompleteWithContact:(nullable CNContact *)contact{
_contact = contact;

    [viewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Below function returns nil:

```
- (CNContact*) getContactFromStoreForIdentifier:(NSString*) identifier
{
    CNContact *updatedContact = nil;

   id descriptor = [CNContactViewController descriptorForRequiredKeys];

CNContactStore *store = [CNContactStore new];

NSError *error;

updatedContact = [store unifiedContactWithIdentifier:identifier
                                         keysToFetch:@[descriptor]
                                               error:&error];
// Found?
if (updatedContact == nil)
{
    if (error != nil)
    {

    }
}
 return updatedContact; }
```

@Parameter: Identifier of CNContact object received from didCompleteWithContact: delegate callback.

Comment: could you share the code where  you create the `CNContactViewController` and implement the delegate methods.

Comment: @JonRose updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a contactStore for the viewController.

```
CNContactStore *store = [CNContactStore new];
contactController.contactStore = store;
```

> If not this property is not set, than adding the contact to the user's
>   contacts is disabled.

source: https://developer.apple.com/reference/contactsui/cncontactviewcontroller/1616912-contactstore

Comment: Thanks @Jon, But this didn't work as well, finally have to use predicate to get newly added contact from store with permanent contact identifier.

Comment: @R.S. I am facing the same issue. how to could you managed here when there were different identifiers?  What is meant by permanent contact identifier?